# Which YAML version is used in Ansible (2.9) playbooks?

Tags: ansible, yaml

### Why YAML 1.2

As per the Ansible docs article [YAML Syntax](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html):

> The list of allowed escapes can be found in the YAML Specification under “Escape Sequences” (YAML 1.1) or “Escape Characters” (**YAML 1.2**).

This might hint to the fact that Ansible does in fact parse the playbooks according to [YAML 1.2](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html). Also, the first Ansible release came in 2012, which is already 3 years after YAML 1.1 has been apparently deprecated (?) in favor of YAML 1.2.

### Why YAML 1.1

On the other hand, the same docs article mentions this:

> Boolean conversion is helpful, but this can be a problem when you want a literal `yes` or other boolean values as a string. In these cases just use quotes. [...]

If I understand correctly, this conversion of `"yes"` to a (boolean) true [has been removed](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2805071) in YAML 1.2.

Also, `yes` (ostensibly evaluated as a boolean true) is shown all over the official user guide (randomly chosen example: [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#hosts-and-users)).

---

I very briefly looked through the [parser code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/stable-2.9/lib/ansible/parsing/yaml) (in the Ansible 2.9 release) and they seem to use custom parsers, not a third-party library. There are few comments and I can't make much sense of it.

Is there a definitive answer to this? I find it very strange that a YAML-oriented software (YAML being a language [notoriously sensitive](https://www.arp242.net/yaml-config.html) to syntactic exactitude, to put it nicely) does not clearly state according to which version of the standard it parses its configuration files.

Comment: Hi zire, welcome to SO. This sounds like a question that you should ask [the ansible project](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues) since (a) it is not asking for help with a specific programming question (b) it is highly unlikely that anyone on SO can state with any authority what the ansible project claims

Comment: @mdaniel Agreed. Should I let moderators close the question, or should I do something myself (delete it?). Thanks for the patience.

Comment: Ansible is using PyYAML, and PyYAML still only implements YAML 1.1 (regarding resolving booleans etc.). There might be YAML 1.2 support in PyYAML at some point, but it can take a while to implement